# Accessing information from Client in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net-ajax, client-side

I have an ASP.Net website where I want to be able to know below things about the person who is browsing my website.

1. logged In user name of OS.
2. Exact OS in (Type of the Os - Windos, Mac etc.: Version of OS).
3. Mac Address
4. IP Address of the client mechine.

my website is a higly secure one and I can fource users to isntall activex and/or some applet if that is required to access the website.

Pleae help me the best way of doing so.

Answer (score 1):

**1** - logged In user name of OS

This is only available if you are using WIndows Forms as your Authentication method, if you are using Forms, you can easily get it's name/user by it's logged in account

**2** - Exact OS in (Type of the Os - Windos, Mac etc.: Version of OS).

We call this [Browser Agent](http://whatsmyuseragent.com/) and you can get it by using in javascript:

```
navigator.userAgent
```

**3** - Mac Address

You can only get the Mac Address of your own server, the one where you have the website hosted, and you can get as many as the network devices that server has, remember that **Mac Address are not unique**!

**4** - IP Address of the client machine.

There is no way to get this with only javascript, you need to use your programming language for, you [should use this](http://thepcspy.com/read/getting_the_real_ip_of_your_users/) to get the real IP Address:

```
string ip = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
if(ip == "") { 
    ip = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]; 
}
```

All together, and using jQuery to be simple:

```
<%
    string ip = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
    if(ip == "") { ip = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]; }
%>
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(function() {

    var ipAddress = '<% = ip %>',
        browser = navigator.userAgent,
        username = <% = Session["username"] %>;

    // now send the data back to your server, if using jQuery, just do:
    $.get("/login-user.aspx", { 
            ip: ipAddress, 
             browser: browser, 
             user: username 
          }, function(data) {
             // use this if you return anything as a response             
          });
   });    
</script>
```

You then can use [http://**UserAgentString.com**/](http://UserAgentString.com/) API to parse your User Agents strings, or use the `navigator` object to get what you want from the browser (or any 3rd party libraries)...

Comment: In your reponse to `logged In user name of OS`, the only way to get this information truthfully is to use NTLM as server authentication and have both machines on the same domain. Even with NTLM is enabled, if the machines are on a separate domain a separate authentication box will be presented and new credentials supplied.